# Why does my image move like this when my menu opens up?

Tags: html, css

If you notice at my site http://imronan.co whenever I press the menu button to show the dropdown menu it appears to shift the image below it over. I'm really confused why this is happening. I'd just like it to shift down when the menu button is pressed to reveal the menu items.

My relevant CSS:

```
body {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
/* bring your own prefixes */
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

a {
color: aliceblue;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
/* no underline */
}

.album {
-webkit-box-reflect: below -10px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top,left bottom, from(transparent), to(rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.1)));
}


.album img {
height: 350px;
width: 350px;
}

...

/*MENU*/
.burgermenu {
z-index: 100000000;
position: static;
margin: 0px 0px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.burgermenu ul {
list-style-type: none; 
list-style-image: none;
}

.burgermenu li {
padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
float: left;    
}

.burgermenu a {
font-weight: 400;
color: burlywood;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000;
}

.burgermenu a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
color: aliceblue;
}
```

Also, anybody know how to fix the reflection so it doesn't glitch when I hover over the menu button?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include  the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. [mcve] A link to your web site is insufficient as, when it gets fixed or goes dead, will make your question and the answers pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add     `margin: auto;` and `width: 350px;` to your `<div class="container">`

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Comment: WOW! Thank you! any idea about the glitchy reflection?

Comment: If you update your website so the image doesnt fit the whole screen i can take a look at it :)

Comment: Is the images supposed to have a reflection?

Comment: So my webhost is being obnoxious and not updating my files via FTP

Comment: Give it a sec :) sometimes it take a minute. Alternatively spam CTRL + F5 (clear cache) if the website doesnt update for you.

Comment: If you take a look now lemme know what you think about that reflection

Comment: Thinking about switching my webhost this one is actually ridiculously slow to update.

Comment: Looks good now, do you want the reflection removed? if so, remove `-webkit-box-reflect` from `.album`in your stylesheet

Comment: No it's just that it disapears on hover of the burgerbutton

Comment: The reason why the reflection disapears is because reflextions doesn't support transitions. So when the button "rotates (make a transition)" the reflection disapears for a second.

Comment: See that's what I was thinking but I wasn't exactly sure how I would get around that :/

Comment: if you need to see the css it's here imronan.co/style/main.css

Comment: I'm going to have to take a look at it late mate, it's 3am here and i am literally sleeping in my chair :)

Comment: I also noticed that it only happen to the burgerbutton but not to the download button.. which confused me even more and means that there should be a workaround

Comment: Well thanks, brotha! let me know if you come up with anything, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

If you go into developer mode and click on the image or the menu bar it will show the CSS change position or the something change anyway. I believe the menu will just be overriding some CSS change. F12 in chrome and you can mess with the CSS

Comment: P.S it only happens if its full screen not when its half screen or smaller.

Comment: I have been inspecting it for hours now. I'm not sure what's wrong with it :/

Answer (score 0):

Just had a look at CSS and html. It is to do with the div tag album. Its changing the size so moves it to the left a bit. You will have to just mess around with that div tag or the CSS

Comment: Its defo to do with that as the image size doesnt change but all the divs change when you click the burger button